# Images doesn't display in my php web application

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php5 and Zend Framework and I'm trying to develop a small web application using them to handle the accounts of a company.

But, no matter what I do, I was unable to insert an image to my file.

Here are my codes:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang = "en">


<style>
</style>

<head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" /></meta>
    <meta name="description" content="" /></meta>
    <title>Accounts Handling</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="menu">
        <?php 
          inlude('C:\wamp\www\Accounts\application\views\scripts\header\header.php');?>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        <p>
    <img src="C:\...\application\views\scripts\images\blue.jpg" alt="blue">
          //the error comes here.
                      </p>

        </div>
        <div><?php 
          inlude('C:\wamp\www\Accounts\application\views\scripts\header\header.php');?>
            </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here I have used the absolute path, but I have tried with relative path="../images/blue.jpg" and also I have tried with the "php include()"

```
<?php 
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
include(__ROOT__.'/blue.jpg'); 
?></div>
```

also, I have tried as,

```
 <?php 
 include('C:\wamp\......\images\blue.jpg'); 
?></div>
```

Please help me to sort this out.. If more details needed, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand the main concept of PHP: it generates HTML code and sends it to browser. Browser reads the code, finds  tags, download images from server and shows them to user. That's how it works.  Browser knows nothing about PHP. And PHP is nothing to do with images.

So you shouldn't use include to insert images - use only  tag. Never use full system path. For example if your image is `C:\wamp\www\images\1.jpg`, the right tag will be `<img src="http://localhost/images/1.jpg">` or you can use relative path.

Answer (score 0):

All images must be stored in the 'public' folder. Then you need to use function  `$this->baseUrl()`
f.e  `<img src="<php echo $this->baseUrl('images/blue.jpg'); ?>" alt="" />`